# Checking shot collisions and removing shot and target in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, removechild

Last year was my first successful year in teaching my students to create catch and avoid games in Flash with AS3. This year is getting better. Each year I come here for help at least once.

I'm trying to add shooting into the possibilities for their second game project. I can make the shot happen from the ship, gun, whatever, and make it move, and get rid of it when it is off screen, but have not figured out a clean way to have both the shot and the target go away (removeChild and array.splice) upon collision.

The code I have *sort of* works, but I keep getting the error,

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.    at
>   DropShootV02_fla::MainTimeline/checkShots()

.
Normally I know that this is because of a mismatch between objects and index numbers, but this is related to the call to a second array in removing boxes and bullets. 
For simplicity I'll just include the shooting code. Similar organization creates and drops the boxes.

Any help is appreciated. BTW we are not using external script in an AS file.

```
var shotSpeed = 18;
var shots:Array = new Array();
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireLaser);
function fireLaser(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (gameOn==true)
    {
        var shot:Shot=new Shot();
        addChild(shot);
        shots.push(shot);
        shot.gotoAndStop(1);
        shot.x = user.x;
        shot.y = user.y;
        trace(shots.length);
    }
}
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveShot);
function moveShot(e:Event):void
{
    for (var i:int=shots.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        shots[i].y -=  shotSpeed;
        if (shots[i].y < -25)
        {
            removeChild(shots[i]);
            shots.splice(i,1);

        }
    }
}
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkShots);
function checkShots(e:Event):void
{
    for (var i:int=shots.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        for (var k:int=boxes.length-1; k>=0; k--)
        {
            if (shots[i].hitTestObject(boxes[k]))
            {
                if (boxes[i].type == "good")
                {
                    score--;
                    scoreDisplay.text = "Score:" + score;
                }
                if (boxes[i].type == "bad")
                {
                    score++;
                }
                removeChild(boxes[k]);
                boxes.splice(k,1);
                //if I leave this part out I get no errors, 
                //but but the bullet goes on to strike again
                removeChild(shots[i]);
                shots.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks kaarto:
I had tried that previously and kept getting the same error. I used that elsewhere in this game code. Turns out I needed to moderate how often the player was shooting. I changed from shooting with the mouse to using space instead and now the problem is gone. Break is definitely a good one here.

Comment: Once you find a hit, you remove a box and a shot. After that happens, inner loop goes for another round with next box, but it tries hitTestObject with the very same shot it already removed. So you must remember to take care of the outer loop too, by `break`ing the inner loop when hit happens.

Comment: @Kaarto is correct, regardless of your limiting how often the player can shoot, if that hit test passes and it's not the last iteration on `k`, it will error on the next iteration as `shots[i]` will no longer exist (because you spliced it out and now `i` will be out of range).      As an aside, you could simplify your removal with `removeChild(boxes.removeAt(k));`  - I'd also recommend amalgamating your enter frame handlers into one for performance reasons.

Comment: @RobCampbell, you may also be interested in checking out the [cseducators.se] community.

Answer (score -2):

Merge `move shot` and `checkShots` in one ENTER_FRAME handler.